# how to use progress bar in pytube3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I know this question has been asked a lot but I tried all the answers and none of them worked.

so I wrote this code to download videos from youtube

```
try:
  from pytube import YouTube
  from pytube import Playlist
except Exception as e:
    print("som module are missing{}".format(e))

link = "a random youtube link"
yt = YouTube(link).streams.get_highest_resolution() 
# I couldn't get the link from user via input since I couldn't
# paste link in pycharm output section)

print(yt.title, " is downloading...")
ytd = yt.download("C:/Users/pedram/OneDrive/Desktop/test")
print("Download Completed!")
```

this code works fine and downloads video from youtube.
but I also wanted to add a download bar so I could see the progress of downloading the video
since pytube didn't work I downloaded pytube3 and I assume that is why most of answers out there doesn't work for me.
if there is anyone who knows what should I do I would appreciate their help.

Answer (score 0):

I think using tqdm library will resolve the problem.
ex.

```
import tqdm
for i in tqdm(some iterator..):
  ...
```

Comment: I see... but there is no iterator in my code so I'm sure if it is useful here

Comment: try ```while (tqdm(YouTube(link).streams.get_highest_resolution())) :```